# Parsing ArrayList of Hashmap in Struts2 tag using s:iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, struts2, hashmap, dynamic-arrays

I have an `ArrayList` containing a `HashMap`, and I am trying to iterate through that `ArrayList` of `HashMap`s using the Struts `s:iterator` tag. I can iterate through the `List` without problems, but I cannot get it to iterate through the entries of the map. So far I've got this:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class mapTest extends ActionSupport {
    public List<Map> listmap;

    public String execute() {
        listmapObject = new ArrayList();
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("stationId", "alpha");
        map.put("stationName", "USA");
        map.put("CustomerName", "charlie"); 
        Map map2 = new HashMap();
        map2.put("stationId", "Beta");
        map2.put("stationName", "UK");
        map2.put("CustomerName", "johnny");
        listmapObject.add(map);
        listmapObject.add(map2);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I need the result like the below Java code equivalent using struts `s:iterator`

```
<table>         
    <thead>
        <th> <Station id> </th>
        <th> station Name </th>
        <th> Name </th>         
    </thead>
    <s:iterator value="listmapObject">
    <tr>
        <td> ((HashMap) listmapObject.get(i)).get("stationId") </td> 
        <td> ((HashMap) listmapObject.get(i)).get("stationName") </td>
        <td> ((HashMap) listmapObject.get(i)).get("CustomerName") </td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator> 
</table>
```

Thanks for everyone for helping me

Comment: have you tried iterating over the hashmap keys?

Comment: yes I tried,using this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433357/iterate-over-a-list-of-maps-using-siterator , But My requirement is different, which is like a Hashmap value should sit in the certain <td> , But the above solution is randomly getting key and value pairs and also I dont want to use LinkedHashMap (which will preserve the order of key and values) because I am accessing that ArrayList of HashMap from third party library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the JSP component of Struts, but I think the following should work:

```
 <s:iterator value="listmapObject">
     <tr>
         <td><s:property value="[0]['stationId']" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="[0]['stationName']" /></td>
         <td><s:property value="[0]['CustomerName']" /></td>
     </tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

According to the [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html), the `[0]` means the list item, so in this case your `HashMap`.